# Updating state of DT and extracting data from DT using State in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, state, dt

`DT` package provides the ability to save the state of a table with filters, searching and everything. I can see the content of that state(`input$TableId_state`) on text output. But I can't use it in any proper way. I want to do two things:

1. Saving a state of DT at any time, and apply it to same DT with an action button. (I want to have full data but with filters and text in search box) .
2. Extracting data from output table into another data table inside server function (not as output table)

I can do 2. bullet by using `input$tableId_rows_all` . But I need to be able to do that with the state.
In my opinion, if any of these are not possible than state function is useless and just to show off.

Here is my trial to do 2. bullet:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "action", label = "Apply",icon=
                 icon("refresh",lib="font-awesome"),style="background-
color:#FBAF16",width =validateCssUnit(385)),
  fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 
"Table")),hr(),fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "FilteredTable"))
)

server <- function(input,output,session){

  output$Table<-DT::renderDataTable(expr = {
    DT::datatable(data,option = list(stateSave = 
TRUE),filter=list(position="top",clear=TRUE))
  })

  filtereddata <- eventReactive(input$action,{
     return(DT::datatable(data
                         ,options = list(state=input$Table_state)
                         ))
  })

  output$FilteredTable<- DT::renderDataTable(expr = {
    return(filtereddata())
  })

}

 runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server),host="127.0.0.2",port=5013, launch.browser = TRUE)
```